# Modify a JSON file with PowerShell without writing BOM

Tags: powershell, unicode, byte-order-mark

I need to modify an existing UTF8 encoded JSON file with PowerShell. I tried with the following code:

```
$fileContent = ConvertFrom-Json "$(Get-Content $filePath -Encoding UTF8)"
$fileContent.someProperty = "someValue"
$fileContent | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 999 | Out-File $filePath
```

This adds a BOM to the file and also encodes it in UTF16. Is it possible to have `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` do not do the encoding / BOM?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `ConvertTo-Json` or `ConvertFrom-Json`. The encoding is defined by the output cmdlet. `Out-File` defaults to Unicode, `Set-Content` to ASCII. With each of them the desired encoding can be defined explicitly:

```
... | Out-File $filePath -Encoding UTF8
```

or

```
... | Set-Content $filePath -Encoding UTF8
```

That will still write a (UTF8) BOM to the output file, but I wouldn't consider UTF-8 encoding without BOM a good practice anyway.

If you want ASCII-encoded output files (no BOM) replace `UTF8` with `Ascii`:

```
... | Out-File $filePath -Encoding Ascii
```

or

```
... | Set-Content $filePath     # Ascii is default encoding for Set-Content
```

Comment: Thanks! The point is that the [JSON spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-3) requires Unicode encoding but doesn't support BOM

Comment: Thanks! My problem was [fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) complained about an unexpected character at position 0 (BOM) when fetching and parsing a file, written using `Out-File`. Setting `-Encoding Ascii`solved my problems.